# Remote Wonder II or similar under Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, remote-control

Under XP I could use a Remote Wonder II from ATI to control my music (play, pause, next, previous, etc). This product does not work under Windows 7 64-bit because of driver issues and it seems to be an orphan product.

My question is: Does a similar product exist that works under Windows 7 64-bit???